# how to change the height of an element depending on the window / document height?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, user-interface, user-experience

I have an element that I need to dynamically change his size depending on the screen resolution, so far I have a fixed size which is `.scroll-sidebars { max-height: 650px; }` but this only works in big screens, as you see in the img below, there is a little margin on the bottom, that's what I want

[image]

if I use that same height on smaller screens, this is what I get

[image]

so I want to avoid that, it doesn't matter that once the height of that panel changes appears a scroll bar on the panel, that is good, all I need is to keep that margin always there at the bottom.

I have a directive, this is an sticky sidebar, I do not know if its helps because maybe we can calculate that height from the directive

```
.directive('sticky', function($document, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var width = $document.width();
      if (width > 991) {
        $timeout(function() {
          angular.element($document).ready(function() {
            var stickySidebar = element,
                stickyHeight,
                sidebarTop,
                scrollTop,
                stickyStop,
                sidebarBottom,
                stopPosition;

            if (stickySidebar.length > 0) {
              stickyHeight = stickySidebar.height();
              sidebarTop = stickySidebar.offset().top;
            }

            $document.scroll(function() {

              if (stickySidebar.length > 0) {
                scrollTop = $document.scrollTop() + 52; //stkicy responds to the navbar
                if (sidebarTop < scrollTop) {
                  stickySidebar.css('top', scrollTop - sidebarTop);
                  sidebarBottom = stickySidebar.offset().top + stickyHeight;
                  stickyStop = $('.main-content').offset().top + $('.main-content').height();
                  if (stickyStop < sidebarBottom) {
                    stopPosition = $('.main-content').height() - stickyHeight;
                    stickySidebar.css('top', stopPosition);
                  }
                }
                else {
                  stickySidebar.css('top', '0');
                }
              }
            });
            $document.resize(function() {
              if (stickySidebar.length > 0) {
                stickyHeight = stickySidebar.height();
              }
            });

          });
        }, 1000);
      }else {
        console.log('do not apply function because the size is not the proper one');
      }
    }
  };
});
```

and the html part

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div sticky>
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Sports</h3><br>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-group">
          <div class="scroll-sidebars">
            <accordion close-others="false">
              <accordion-group ng-repeat="sport in sports">
                <accordion-heading>
                  <div>
                    {{::sport.name}}
                  </div>
                </accordion-heading>
                <div>
                     {{::league.name}}
                </div>
              </accordion-group>
            </accordion>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vh on your css, no need to use JS, however, if you need support for old browsers you'll need JS :(

```
.scroll-sidebars {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.scroll-sidebars { max-height: 90%; }`

Defining a px number will always cause the section to take up that many pixels. No matter the screen size. so if I have a large screen with a low resolution, the same issue occurs.

When using percentages, the CSS uses the browser's height and width to determine how large to make the containing section.

Comment: I've been trying to play with the ```%``` instead of ```px``` but it doesn't work for me. See my update

Comment: maybe i didn't explain, myself, if I put ```px``` works, you can see the height changing, but with ```%``` nothing changes, it doesn't matter the percentage i put, would be always 100 %, so it is not taking ```%```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function `calc` assuming you do not care about [old browsers not supporting it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) :

```
.scroll-sidebars { 
    max-height: calc(100% - 50px); 
}
```

The above rule will set the height to 100% *of the container's height*, minus 50px (adjust this value to your needs).

You could define a height according to the viewport height. The viewport is the visible portion of the document. Note that you can use it with [these browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units). The following makes use of the `vh` unit, which stands for viewport height.

```
.scroll-sidebars { 
    max-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

Comment: so what magic number would you put in the 50px section to make sure that the window isn't as tall as the number your subtracting, making the section invisible? (thinking about more applications than just the case provided)

Comment: Well I wouldn't have suggested that solution if the OP was designing a webapp for a smart watch. I suggested to substract 50px as an example, I leave the OP to adjust it, and yes, it is under the assumption the container height is bigger than 'that little margin to substract'

Comment: look at the html part for you to see where ```.scroll-sidebars``` begins

Comment: You probably mean that a parent element has already an constrained height, thus `100%` of the height is also constrained, is that it?

Comment: yes, I mean, is just that the percentage sign doesn't do anything, is doesn't affect anything. if I use it nothing changes, only using px

Comment: Completed the answer with viewport information. As for the fact that the percentage value is not taken into account, that would be hard to tell without the hierarchy of your element and the styles applied on it

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$document.resize()` use `$window.onresize` which is pure javascript `onresize` event. Before doing this add `$window` dependency

**CODE**

```
$window.onresize = function() {
    if (stickySidebar.length > 0) {
      stickyHeight = stickySidebar.height();
    }
};
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: ok but, what it would change ? look at my code so you can see what I want to change.

Comment: yes, I got it, but what's the difference my friend ?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer to call code on viewport changes